# How to render html page code from ajax response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I am implementing JavaScript authentication and I want to open some html file when user has logged in successfully. 
When user enters username and password I send ajax request to the server where I'm validating user's credentials. If validation was successful I send another ajax request to the registered route ("dashboard"). As a response from ajax request I have the whole html page code. How can I render this code at the registered route (dashboard in my case)?

Here is my code

Client:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "signinUser", 
    method: "GET", 
    headers: {"Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(name + ":" + pass)}, 
    success: function(result) { 
        $.ajax({
            url: "dashboard", 
            method: "GET", 
            success: function(result) { 
                console.log(result);            
            }
        });                 
    }
});
```

Server:

```
app.get('/dashboard', function (req, res) { 
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dashboard.html'));
});
```

Comment: i'm not sure but maybe `$('html').html(result)` would work

Comment: If it's a whole HTML page, wouldn't it be easier to just redirect to that page?

Comment: $('html').html(result) works but I want this page to be at specific route . In my case it's "dashboard"

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
document.location.href = '/dashboard';
```

In your specific case:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "signinUser", 
    method: "GET", 
    headers: {"Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(name + ":" + pass)}, 
    success: function(result) { 
        document.location.href = '/dashboard';
        // or
        /* document.location.href = result.url; // for dynamic redirect */
    }
});
```